# Qual è il significato di "smargiassante" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La nascita del giullare* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> Ma un giorno tornando dal campo attraverso la riva del fiume in cerca di qualche granchio… ho perso il 
>   cammino e, di botto, mi sono trovato davanti a una montagna nera che non conoscevo. 
>   
>          Tremenda, alta! 
>    
>    ‎       E ho domandato a un carrettiere che passava di lí: –
>   Compare, di chi è questa montagna **smargiassante**
>   che si rizza all’improvviso?

In parecchi dizionari ho trovato che "smargiassare" significa fare lo smargiasso, cioè, fare lo spaccone, il fanfarone. Tuttavia, questo non sembra avere molto senso in questo contesto. Potreste spiegarmi qual è il senso di "smargiassante" nel passaggio sopra citato?

Answer (score 1):

"Smargiassare" significa appunto fare lo spaccone; in questo caso si sta utilizzando il participio presente del verbo come un aggettivo, per caratterizzare la montagna; questo utilizzo è assai comune in italiano:
http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/participio_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/

Nel brano in questione sta secondo me a indicare che la montagna si innalzava in modo così alto e ripido, da sembrare voler sbarrare il passo ai viandanti con un atteggiamento da gradasso. Potrebbe anche essere un modo che ha il personaggio parlante per esorcizzare il timore che incute il vedere questa montagna ergersi all'improvviso.